# How to use Utility libraries within Generators

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, monorepo, nrwl-nx

Needs to create Generator that prepares the static JSON data.

The implementation of the data forming is located in a Utility library which is available across the monorepo but `tools` directory where it is supposed to use.

How to set up the `tsconfig.json` within `tools` dir to make the Utility library available for Executors?

```
apps
libs
- utils
  - my-lib
tools
- generators
  - my-generator
```

The `my-lib` library is available in apps and other libs as `@my-workspace/utils/my-lib` but in the code of executors is not:

```js
import { Tree } from '@nrwl/devkit';

import { myLibGenerator } from '@my-workspace/utils/my-lib'; // <-- TS2307: Cannot find module '@my-workspace/utils/my-lib' or its corresponding type declarations. 

export default async function (tree: Tree) {
  const data = await myLibGenerator(tree);
  return () => {
    console.log('Process finished', data);
  };
}
```